# Scraping "a" tags b/w "p" tags using JSoup

Tags: java, regex, web-scraping, jsoup

I am scraping a website, and a paragraph of interest to me contains many **a** tags. The situation is something like:

```
<p>
    <a></a>
    Some text
    <a></a>
    Some text
</p>
```

I am successful in extracting all the text within the **p** tags, except for the text of the **a** tags. Due to this, the continuity of the text is lost and it becomes very-much unreadable.

I need to extract everything inside the **p** tags as text. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, you want to use the [`text`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text--) method on the `p` element:

> Gets the combined text of this element and all its children. Whitespace is normalized and trimmed.
>
> For example, given HTML `<p>Hello <b>there</b> now! </p>`, `p.text()` returns `"Hello there now!"`
>
> **Returns:**
>
> unencoded, normalized text, or empty string if none.

(Contrast with [`ownText`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--), [`textNodes`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#textNodes--).)

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Also, a lesson for me to read the relevant documentation first before posting on SO.